# Is this nstoolbar? How to achieve such an effect?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsscrollview

[image]

When I run reminder app on Mac OS 11, I find its NSSplitview very interesting. The height of its left and right NSToolbar is inconsistent, and when I scroll the content, there will be a shadow like line on it.

I've tried this shadow. I don't know if it's set by titlebar separator style.

I tried to implement it in my own application, but I found three problems.

1. I can't make the height of NSToolbar different on both sides of NSSplitview.
2. I can't show this shadow for my NSScrollview
3. I found that even if I use titlebar accessory view controller, I can't achieve the same style as it.

Answer (score 0):

According to UI Inspector, that's not a part of NSToolbar. Just a custom view.

[image]